# How to link HTML5 input to two forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input that's used by JS to control submitting two forms with different actions, but only one of them will be submitted and it should include this input.

I can do it with a hidden input using JS to change their values when the original one changes but I'd like to know if there is an HTML5 solution.

Here is my JS code to do it:

```
$(function(){
  $('#originalOne').change(function(){
    // check if I should disable a form
    $('.hiddenOnes').val($(this).val());
  })
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are unable to merge the two forms, and have a single submit button?

Comment: one of them can be disabled and they have different actions edited the question to clarify that

Comment: When do you want the second form to be submitted, if ever? Since the two have different actions it seems a `<fieldset>` might not be very useful.

Comment: @gyre i will make ajax request to check the database, if the record has been already inserted the form will be disabled (both forms can be disabled but not related to each other so both/none/one of them can be disabled)

Comment: That makes a little more sense, but I don't know if I have enough information yet to solve your problem. Could you post the rest of your HTML and JS code so I could get a better sense of the bigger picture?

Comment: that's alot and will be complicated
the idea is i have two forms insert into two tables in the database
the user enter the date i check if he inserted that date before in either of them if yes i disable the form so that he don't submit two rows with the same date

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be understanding what you are asking, correct me if I'm wrong:

"Is there a way to update the values in one form based on the values in another using HTML5 only (without using JavaScript)?"

Unfortunately, the answer there is NO. You will need to attach event listeners and handle changes using JavaScript. I had previously suggested using a [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) to group the inputs that you wanted to disable independently, but this method does not work for multiple form actions.